# contentEditable with move cursor and resize handles

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

With the `contentEditable` attribute set to `false` we have been able to get a non-editable area in Telerik RadEditor.

```cs
<telerik:RadEditor ID="reText" runat="server">
    <Content>foo bar ------------ <span contentEditable="false">non-editable comment</span> --------------- foo bar.</Content>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

When the non-editable block is selected in IE8 a `move` cursor and resize handles are displayed:

[image: IE8]

But IE10+ doesn't seem to able to display those resize handles:

[image: IE10+]

The resize handles are rendered and controlled by IE and not by the RadEditor. Telerik support told us we can use the following approach:

```cs
<telerik:RadEditor ID="reText" runat="server" EnableImmutableElements="true">
    <Content>foo bar ------------ <span style="display:inline-block" contentEditable="false">non-editable comment</span> --------------- foo bar
    </Content>
</telerik:RadEditor>
```

But the appearance of the resize handles are not something which the RadEditor can control as they are implemented in the browser's logic. This gives a `move` cursor but not the resize handles, thus the user can't see that the content is selected.

[image: IE11 alternative]

Any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<span style="display:inline-block; cursor: default;" contentEditable="false">
```

to see if you can override the cursor? Adding the `!important` modifier may also help.

I tried things on e VM with IE8 and the resize handles were still there, though. Such browser behaviors may not even have a workaround.